# How to use behaivors in Polymer 1.0 to imitate extends in polymer 0.5

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am migrating my code from v0.5 to v1.0. I have a piece of code which somewhat looks like this.

```
   <polymer-element name="common-view">
    <template>
     <paper-spinner id='spiner1'></paper-spinner>
    </template>
   <script>
    Polymer({
        created: function() {
          console.log("common-view created");
        }
    });
  </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

So, this view was extended in other views. I used to get the paper-spinner element and other methods and properties in the views which extended this particular element. Now, in v1.0 I understand there is no concept of inheritance yet but we can share the behaivors using behaivors object.

My question is whether the behaviours object has to be in the form of script and polymer 1.0 does not support putting elements in the behaviours and using them in places where I will use the behaviour ? If not, is there a way to achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you currently can't extend Polymer elements although you may be able to in a future release.

A behavior is written as a HTML file with some JavaScript in that defines the behaviour. You can't put an element in this. You would need to write a behavior and then implement that in your elements that you want to have that behavior. Google did a great tutorial video on this which you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrlmieL3Z0k).

Comment: I watched the video and tried to implement the behaivors. But I am facing the following problem. The life-cycle callback "created" of the behaivor is called before the "created" method of the element using the behaivor. Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong.

In the video it is mentioned that the behaivor callback is called after the element life-cycle callbacks